# Find the difference between two model field

Tags: python, django

I want to find the difference between **quantity** of Product class and **sold_quantity** of Stock class. How do I do that

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Stock(models.Model):
    sold_quantity = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name
```

Comment: To do that, you need instances of both class Product and Stock, did you test something? can you show some tries?

Answer (score 1):

For **one** instance you can do this by:

*Example: id=1*

```py
product_instance = Product.objects.get(id=1)
quantity_difference = product_instance.quantity - product_instance.stock.sold_quantity
```

> *Note: This assumes the relationship is coupled between models.*